# Net core 3.0 with Autofac throw IServiceProvider isn't supported

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, .net-core, autofac

I have some trouble i try to resolve problem i use Autofac with .net core 3.0-6preview.
I add `new AutofacServiceProviderFactory()` to `CreateHostBuilder which` is require in this .net core version framework.
The code was working correctly in version 2.1 and lower but now application was crashed

> The exception:
>       System.NotSupportedException: 'ConfigureServices returning an System.IServiceProvider isn't supported.'

The Program class code:

```cs
     public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args) => CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseServiceProviderFactory(new AutofacServiceProviderFactory())
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                });
    }
```

And the Startup class:

```cs
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        public IContainer ApplicationContainer { get; private set; }


        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
            builder.Populate(services);
            builder.RegisterModule(new ContainerModule(Configuration));
            ApplicationContainer = builder.Build();
            return new AutofacServiceProvider(ApplicationContainer);
        }
```

```cs
        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, IApplicationLifetime appLifetime)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });


            var jwtSettings = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<JwtSettings>();
            var generalSettings = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<GeneralSettings>();
            if (generalSettings.SeedData)
            {
                var dataInitializer = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IDataInitializer>();
                dataInitializer.SeedAsync();
            }

            //           app.UseMvc();
            appLifetime.ApplicationStopped.Register(() => ApplicationContainer.Dispose());

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Startup syntax has changed for configuring Autofac.

Instead, in `Startup` do the following

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
    //... normal registration here

    // Add services to the collection. Don't build or return
    // any IServiceProvider or the ConfigureContainer method
    // won't get called.
}

public void ConfigureContainer(ContainerBuilder builder) {
    //configure auto fac here
    builder.RegisterModule(new ContainerModule(Configuration));
}
```

Reference [Autofac documentation](https://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/integration/aspnetcore.html#asp-net-core-3-0-and-generic-hosting) for ASP.NET Core 3.0+

Answer (score 0):

you must change program.c

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
       WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
           .ConfigureLogging(options => options.ClearProviders())
           .UseStartup<Startup>();
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).